# Content is coming out of lightning card in lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-card, lightning-layouts

I have a form where I need to display few details of logged in person on customer community. I am using lightning layout and layout item within a lightning card. I have first name with 40 chars and family name with 80 chars. Though used attributes flexibility=auto and size used in layout item the content seems to come out of the lightning card, looking as in snapshot below.
I have already tried using a layout within layout with all available attributes but no luck. Can someone point me in right direction? Below is the code

```
<template>
<lightning-card title="details">
    <lightning-button label="Edit" id="details" slot="actions" onclick={handleClick}></lightning-button>
    <lightning-layout horizontal-align="start" multiple-rows="true">
        <lightning-layout-item flexibility="auto" size="4" padding="horizontal-medium">
            <p ><b>name:</b></p>
        </lightning-layout-item>
        <lightning-layout-item flexibility="auto"  size="8">
            <p >firstnameeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee lastnameeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeemwmwmwmwmwmwmwmmwmwwmwmwmwmwmwmmwmwmwwwwm</p>
        </lightning-layout-item>          
    </lightning-layout>
</lightning-card>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue can be handled in css. You need to wrap everything inside the `lightning-layout-item` in a div with custom class

```
<lightning-layout-item flexibility="auto"  size="8">
    <div class="u-break-word">
        <p >firstnameeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee lastnameeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeemwmwmwmwmwmwmwmmwmwwmwmwmwmwmwmmwmwmwwwwm</p>
    </div>
</lightning-layout-item>
```

CSS change

```
.u-break-word {
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: This seems to work for me